# Angular way to get the properties of the outer html element

Tags: html, angular, angular6

In my app I have a deeply nested components structure. I have a component with a very long form which is scrolling vertically. Inside that scrolling block I have components with a 'cog' icon. When you click that icon, a popover should appear next to it (inside the scrolling block).

However, the popover should consider the height of that scrolling block. And depending on the position of the 'cog' icon should appear either to the bottom or to the top of it in order to fit within the scrolling block.

So, to summarise, I somehow need to know the innerHeight of the scrolling block contents and its absolute position (getBoundingClientRect) in order to position my popover properly.

Right now I've done it using the html element id. And then simply find element by id in the popover component constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document) {
    this.scrollingBlock = doc.getElementById('scrollingBlock');
}
```

And then simply get the properties I need from it. Like the following:

```
this.scrollingBlockHeight = (this.scrollingBlock.firstChild as HTMLElement).scrollHeight;
this.scrollingBlockRect = this.scrollingBlock.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Although, everything works now, I believe it's not very elegant/Angular-way solution. I'm using Angular 6 for my app. Is there any better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: You could create a directive and access it using `ElementRef` and use `Renderer2` to update / manipulate / get properties from your dom element: https://medium.com/@kmathy/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba